# How can I use Flash AS 3.0 read realtime file.txt?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I use Flash AS 3.0 read realtime file.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, if the data you are attempting to read has any structure whatsoever you'd be better off using XML, here's how to achieve this using a URLLoader:

```
var txtLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

txtLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onTxtLoaded);

function onTxtLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.target.data); // will return content of text file
}

txtLoader.load(new URLRequest("textFile.txt"));
```

Where textFile.txt is in the same directory as your published swf